# ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' trying to use Gatsby with MUI and Styled-Components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby, styled-components

I am trying to use Gatsby with MUI and Styled-Components. However I get the following error message: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' that is unusual because the docs say that styled-components can be used [exclusively as the styling solution](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/styled-engine/).

Steps to reproduce:

1. run `gatsby new` selecting defaults and styled-components as styling system
2. run `npm install --save @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components` from the mui install [instructions](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/) for styled-components
3. add `import Button from "@mui/material/Button";` to the imports and `<Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>` in the main div of the index.js file. From the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/usage/).
4. try `gatsby develop` but it will fail with `ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@emotion/react'` this is the problem.

What I tried:

- I tried `npm i --save @emotion/react @emotion/styled` and the button renders but i'm not sure if it renders with styled-components or emotion, probably emotion.
- I tried to alias @mui/styled-engine to @mui/styled-engine-sc the wrapper around styled-components as described [here in the mui docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/styled-engine/) and [here in the Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-alias-imports/) but I don't think that's related to my problem because if anything i would need to alias @emotion/styled to some other package.
- I looked at [Gatsby theme materialui](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-theme-material-ui/) but that mentions SSR and the docs says SSR doesn't work with styled-components and npm [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/styled-engine/). Do I have to use Yarn?

Related SO Questions:

- [material-ui-v5-not-working-styled-components-and-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69223243/material-ui-v5-not-working-styled-components-and-typescript)
- [using-material-ui-theming-with-styled-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852615/using-material-ui-theming-with-styled-component)

Other related links:

- this [Github example](https://github.com/brendanpowershifter/Gatsby-MUI-Styled-Components-Example) uses gatsby-theme-material-ui but i think that uses SSR which is [broken](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/styled-engine/) with npm and styled-components.

Best solution I found so far is to not use styled-components and rather use emotion and the styled() option from @mui/styled as described [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29742#issuecomment-1011143802).

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are indeed not clear, you have to add these dev dependecies and this resolution part in your `package.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.4",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mui/styled-engine": "npm:@mui/styled-engine-sc@latest",
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@mui/styled-engine": "npm:@mui/styled-engine-sc@latest"
  }
}
```

And also this one in devDependencies in you use Typescript: `"@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",`